# Reference the inputs created with ng-repeat in angular based on the number of variable options

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The problem I'm facing, as outlined in the code, is that I can't seem to find out how to bind the second checkboxes (created with ng-repeat) to some model which I would then be able to use further down the code (showing/hiding yet another set of options). Also, I managed to show the additional number of inputs based on the `count` parameter in the `$scope.availableOptions` by using the `$scope.getItterator` function, but now I don't see how would I access the values of these checkboxes? I know I have to somehow use the option "ng-model" but am failing to do so, so any help appreciated.

My code is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CkHhJ/25/), but am showing it here too:

html:

```
<div ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
    Show additional options <input type="checkbox" ng-model="additionalOptions">
    <div ng-show="additionalOptions">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="option in availableOptions">
                <label class="checkbox" for="opt_{{option.id}}">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="opt_{{option.id}}" id="opt_{{option.}}" />
                    {{option.name}}

                    <ul ng-show="if the upper checkbox is clicked">
                        <li>
                            <input type="text" ng-repeat="i in getItterator(option.count)" ng-model="SOME_VALUE_TO_BE_USED_BELOW"/>
                            Output the value based on what's entered above in the textboxes (SOME_VALUE_TO_BE_USED_BELOW)
                        </li>   
                    </ul>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my js:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.availableOptions = [{"id":"1","name":"easy","count":"2"},{"id":"2","name":"medium","count":"3"},{"id":"3","name":"hard","count":"2"}];

    $scope.getItterator=function(n){
        var a = new Array();

        for(var i=1; i <= n; i++)
            a.push(i);

        return a;       
    };

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ng-model="option.checked"`:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="opt_{{option.id}}" id="opt_{{option.}}" ng-model="option.checked"/>
```

And then you can access this property further below like this:

```
<ul ng-show="option.checked">
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xxRy3/)

If you need to also reference the text box inputs. You create a new property (`values`) on the option. Like this:

```
{"id":"1","name":"easy","count":"2",values:[]}
```

Html:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in getItterator(option.count)">
     <input type="text"  ng-model="option.values[$index]"/>
      {{option.values[$index]}}
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xxRy3/1/)

Comment: Ok, great, thank you. Now, this solves my first issue. However, can you please tell me how would I then refer to the value someone puts in the input boxes under these second set of checkboxes?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="opt_{{option.id}}" id="opt_{{option.}}" ng-model="option.clicked"/>
    {{option.name}}

<ul ng-show="option.clicked">
```

Basically, you are saying that the top checkbox should store its value in a model for each option `option.clicked`. And then only showing the information based on the scope item.

Updated Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CkHhJ/26/

UPDATE:

Here is another updated fiddle to answer your questions second part: http://jsfiddle.net/CkHhJ/27/

The difficulties you were having is likely because you are trying to build dynamic input models. Just bear in mind that you need to use an object for the dynamic values (not a plain string, eg: `option.answers[$index].value` and not just `option.answers[$index]`. See: [AngularJS: Updating an input with a dynamic ng-model blurs on each key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340555/angularjs-updating-an-input-with-a-dynamic-ng-model-blurs-on-each-key-press)

Comment: Ok, great, thank you. Now, this solves my first issue. However, can you please tell me how would I then refer to the value someone puts in the input boxes under these second set of checkboxes?

Comment: I've expanded on the answer for you :)